# Cannot resolve symbol 'android' and 'adRequest'

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have created an app with cordova CLI added android platform and added the source code in the Android studio. It was working fine but when I added admob plugin through cordova CLI I'm getting following errors.

> 1.cannot resolve symbol android
>
> 2.cannot resolve symbol adRequest

Note:
Google Services are installed
I also built another app a week ago and also added admob and that was working fine.

[[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you provide the corresponding `build.gradle`? I believe it is missing a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
```

to the `build.gradle` of the module as dependency.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: After adding these I'm now getting these errors, Grade Del method not found: 'compile' Possible causes: The project android may be using a version of gradle that doesn't contain the method

Comment: 2.The build file may be missing a great a gradle plugin.

Comment: Put it in an dependencies tag. As you are defining a dependency to gms at compile timr here. See the link for an example. Android Studio will recognize this and the errors should go away.